# Compare multiple objects in the array and sum values when a certain common value, JavaScript / Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

This might be an easy task to solve for more experienced programmers. I have been searching for answers for a while but somehow I haven't found a solution yet. So, my problem is following.

**There is an array of multiple objects, for example in my case:**

```js
const array = [
  {Id: 0, Name: 'John', Currency: 'USD', Amount: 25},
  {Id: 1, Name: 'Matt', Currency: 'EUR', Amount: 460},
  {Id: 2, Name: 'Lisa', Currency: 'YEN', Amount: 60000},
  {Id: 3, Name: 'Pete', Currency: 'EUR', Amount: 2400}
]
```

As you can see, there are similarities between the object values. In my case, I would like to have a solution where all the same currencies and their values are combined::

*(e.g. Currency: 'EUR' (obj1 & obj2), Amount: 460 (obj1) + 2400 (obj2) = 2860)*

**So, the final result would look something like this:**

```js
const finalarray = [
  {Currency: 'USD', Amount: 25},
  {Currency: 'EUR', Amount: 2860},
  {Currency: 'YEN', Amount: 60000}
]
```

I personally, don't mind if the other keys of the object don't exist in the final array, as long as:

**1)** The objects of the array compare one of their values with all the other values of the same key, *and*

**2)** The amounts with the value of a certain same key are combined with each other, all of them.

I'm working with a Vue.js project, so I need the language to be JavaScript. What comes to the answer, the simpler the better as I'd like to keep the code as compact as possible. But the most important thing is that it solves the problem. I'm having a *Computed* property *currencyList()* that is going to return the new array.

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Run through it with and store the unique id's (currency) in a Map. and just append to that map the values. and in the end print the map values or entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick solution I thought of was:

```
const accumulator = (array) => array.reduce((res, item) =>
              res.set(item.Currency, (res.get(item.Currency)||0) + item.Amount), new Map());

const values = Array.from(accumulator(array), item => ({item[0]: item[1]}))
```

The cost is O(n) So thats fine. you can probably prettify it

Comment: Thanks man, this is just what I needed! Works great and the code is short and clean, and you delivered it in decent time. I really appriciate your effort with this, also learned a lot. Keep up the good work.